# Вирусы в файлах сайта

Tags: уязвимости, php, html, javascript, вирусы

Недавно произошел со мной случай, попался вирус - скрипт. заразил все сайты (не работали, вели по рефералу), Скрипт оказался очень заразным. Все сайты находящиеся на хостинге тоже умерли. Каким образом он туда попал ? Я ничего не грузил в корни сайтов.

Вопрс: Как можно защитится от подобных вещей ?

Comment: Может просто на вашем хостинге велись технические работы?

Проверьте почту об этом всего предупреждают.

А если это и был скрипт то это максимум JS, думаю вряд ли скрипт JS в силах завалить хост.

Comment: Хорошие такие работы по заражению сайта xD

Comment: Хостинг от ihc.ru
Вирус был странный в теге <script></script>. Много разных каракуль.

Comment: Тут либо первый пункт либо третий. Это, кстати, не каракули, а закодированная строка загружающая вирус.

Comment: Я знаю, просто эта хрень мне убила 15 сайтов. И не только мои.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Вирус попал к вам на комп, украл сохраненный пароли от фтп, после чего произошло заражение. Решение: хороший антивирус.
2. Дырявый хостинг, взломали его, заразили и вас. Решение: не использовать говнохостигн за 3 гроша.
3. Дырявая CMS, которую взломали и провели заражение.  Решение: либо обновить систему с учётом последних секьюрити фиксов, либо не использовать.  Вот в целом и всё.

Answer (score 3):

Плюсую к [[@Зоркий](/users/2410/%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)](/users/2410/%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и добавлю от себя: сталкивался с этой проблемой несколько раз. Помогала смена паролей + писал скрипт, пробегающий по всем файлам и "отрубающий" хвосты.

**Добавлено**

```
<?
$RD = dirname(__FILE__);
function delVirus($dir)
{
    $m = glob($dir.'/*.js');
    $ml = sizeof($m);
    if($m)
        for($i = 0; $i < $ml; ++$i)
        {
            $t = file_get_contents($m[$i]);
            echo '['.$m[$i].']';
            if($s = strpos($t, "var _0x5cb4"))
            {
                $t = substr($t, 0, $s);
                $t = file_put_contents($m[$i], $t);
                echo ' +';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }

    if(!$handle = opendir($dir))
        break;
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file))
        {
            delVirus($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
}
delVirus($RD);
?>
```

Этот вариант удаляет из `*.js` все, что начинается с `var _0x5cb4`. Если вирусня полезла в php и начинается с другой строки, скрипт легко отредактировать.

Comment: не можешь поделиться скриптом ? А то вручную все удалять себе дороже.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Извини, а как запустить скрип по всем вложенным каталогам.

Comment: Загрузите его в корневую папку и откройте в браузере.

Comment: Пожалуйста). Скрипт будет считаться рабочим, пока вирусописатели не начнут пихать по файлам разные скрипты. Тогда поможет только откат файлов.

Comment: На самом деле, есть вирусы которые прописывают себя и в php файлы, поэтому проверять нужно весь сайт и откат тут делать не обязательно. Есть такая замечателньая среда разработки - ZDE, там можно задать поиск по всем файлам сайта лежащи на хосте, или любой папке. Вводим в поиск <script или <iframe или любой кусок вируса и он сам всё найдет. Пусть машина работает :) зачем что-то писать :)

Comment: @Зоркий, я более того скажу: в Notepad++ тоже есть замена в файлах, работающая и в подпапках. =) Но стоит ли для этого качать сайт целиком?  
По поводу расширения файлов: сначала надо посмотреть, какие типы файлов лечить, а потом уже приниматься за работу.